# How can I add a score counter to update the score on a game when a square with a value of 1 clicked?

Tags: javascript, arrays, counter

[asteroid image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfMRQ.png) [space-stars image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tu6uq.png).

I'm creating a game to collect asteroids. When the value of 1 is clicked, the score should get incremented by 1. I want the squares to be hidden initially and then revealed when the square is clicked (1=asteroid image, 0=space image) Can someone help with figuring out how to add the counter correctly? I've added comments "//for counter" for the lines I added which are not working.

I seem to have changed something right before posting this question(not sure what) so clicking the asteroid squares no longer clears the board, hence the edit.

```js
// Maze dimensions
const rows = 10;
const columns = 10;

// Number of asteroids to collect
const totalAsteroids = 17;

// Maze array generation
const maze = Array.from({ length: rows }, () => Array(columns).fill(0));

// Place the asteroids randomly
let asteroidsPlaced = 0;
while (asteroidsPlaced < totalAsteroids) {
  const randomRow = Math.floor(Math.random() * rows);
  const randomColumn = Math.floor(Math.random() * columns);

  if (maze[randomRow][randomColumn] === 0) {
    maze[randomRow][randomColumn] = 1;
    asteroidsPlaced++;
  }
}

// Initialize game state
let asteroidsCollected = 0;
let maxAsteroids = totalAsteroids;

// Get elements from HTML
const boardElement = document.getElementById('board');
const messageElement = document.getElementById('message');
const scoreBoard = document.getElementById('counter');

messageElement.innerHTML = "Welcome! Start collecting asteroids!";
scoreBoard.innerHTML = "Score: 0"; // for counter

let score = 0;

// Function to handle square clicks
function squareClicked(row, column) {
  const squareValue = maze[row][column];

  if (squareValue === 1) {

    maze[row][column] = 0;
    asteroidsCollected++;  //for the counter
    scoreBoard.innerHTML = "Score: " + asteroidsCollected;  //for counter

    updateBoard();


    if (asteroidsCollected === totalAsteroids) {
      messageElement.textContent = "Congratulations! You found all the asteroids!";
    }
  }    

}

// Function to update the board
function updateBoard() {
  boardElement.innerHTML = '';


  for (let row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
    for (let column = 0; column < columns; column++) {
      const squareValue = maze[row][column];

      const square = document.createElement('div');
      square.className = 'maze-square';

      if (squareValue === 1) {
        square.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfMRQ.png')";
            score++;        //for counter

      } else {
        square.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tu6uq.png')";
      }

      square.style.opacity = 0; // Hide the squares initially
      square.addEventListener('click', () => {
        square.style.opacity = 1;
        squareClicked(row, column); //for counter

      });
      
      boardElement.appendChild(square);
      
    }

  }

}
// Initial board update
updateBoard();
```

```css
.maze-square {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: contain;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#board{
  width: 500px;
  height: 540px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
  background-image: url(space.svg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
#message{
  width: 600px;
  height: 64px;
  line-height: 64px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: aliceblue;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
  position:relative;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: block;
  margin-left: 300px;
}
#counter{
  position:fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p id="message"></p>
<div id="board"></div>
<h1 id="counter"></h1>
```

Comment: I've edited your question so that the code can be run in a snippet.  Since you game links to images that are not able to be shown here, you should probably edit the code so people can see what to click on

Comment: @ChrisBarr Thanks a lot Chris. I've added the images and have edited the code as advised. I ran the code in the snippet you created and ran into the same issue I ran into earlier, where clicking on the square with the asteroid image (value of 1) increments the score, but instead of revealing image in the clicked square, it hides the other squares that have already been revealed. The counter continues to increment the score correctly so I'm obviously doing something wrong with the click function, but I cannot figure out how to fix it or where my mistake is.

Comment: "squares to be hidden initially and then revealed when the square is clicked " Say what? What squares are you clicking? just like if you said "make them pink until clicked then make them pink" this needs clarity

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Sorry. By that I mean for the image in the square to be hidden and revealed when the square in the maze is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So all I had to do was comment out the `updateBoard()` inside of the `squareClicked` function and that made it not clear the board out any more.

The problem is that when `updateBoard` is called, it create all the `div` elements you can click on. If you re-create all the HTML inside of the game every time you click on something, that will most certainly clear things out.  Just removint this line fixes it.

How did I find this out?  I just commented stuff out to see what caused the bug. It happens when you click on something, so first I commented out the call to `squareClicked` inside the click function.  This made the images stay on the board, which confirmed it has to do with the click. Everything inside the `squareClicked` function makes sense except for the call back to `updateBoard`.

```js
// Maze dimensions
const rows = 10;
const columns = 10;

// Number of asteroids to collect
const totalAsteroids = 17;

// Maze array generation
const maze = Array.from({ length: rows }, () => Array(columns).fill(0));

// Place the asteroids randomly
let asteroidsPlaced = 0;
while (asteroidsPlaced < totalAsteroids) {
  const randomRow = Math.floor(Math.random() * rows);
  const randomColumn = Math.floor(Math.random() * columns);

  if (maze[randomRow][randomColumn] === 0) {
    maze[randomRow][randomColumn] = 1;
    asteroidsPlaced++;
  }
}

// Initialize game state
let asteroidsCollected = 0;
let maxAsteroids = totalAsteroids;

// Get elements from HTML
const boardElement = document.getElementById('board');
const messageElement = document.getElementById('message');
const scoreBoard = document.getElementById('counter');

messageElement.innerHTML = "Welcome! Start collecting asteroids!";
scoreBoard.innerHTML = "Score: 0"; // for counter

let score = 0;

// Function to handle square clicks
function squareClicked(row, column) {
  const squareValue = maze[row][column];

  if (squareValue === 1) {

    maze[row][column] = 0;
    asteroidsCollected++;  //for the counter
    scoreBoard.innerHTML = "Score: " + asteroidsCollected;  //for counter

    //updateBoard(); //<--- I commented this out
    if (asteroidsCollected === totalAsteroids) {
      messageElement.textContent = "Congratulations! You found all the asteroids!";
    }
  }    

}

// Function to update the board
function updateBoard() {
  boardElement.innerHTML = '';

  for (let row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
    for (let column = 0; column < columns; column++) {
      const squareValue = maze[row][column];

      const square = document.createElement('div');
      square.className = 'maze-square';

      if (squareValue === 1) {
        square.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfMRQ.png')";
            score++;        //for counter

      } else {
        square.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tu6uq.png')";
      }

      square.style.opacity = 0; // Hide the squares initially
      square.addEventListener('click', () => {
        square.style.opacity = 1;
        squareClicked(row, column); //for counter
      });
      
      boardElement.appendChild(square);
    }
  }

}
// Initial board update
updateBoard();
```

```css
.maze-square {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: contain;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#board{
  width: 500px;
  height: 540px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
  background-image: url(space.svg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
#message{
  width: 600px;
  height: 64px;
  line-height: 64px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: aliceblue;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
  position:relative;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: block;
  margin-left: 175px;
}
#counter{
  position:fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p id="message"></p>
<div id="board"></div>
<h1 id="counter"></h1>
```